# Navigate to Experience cloud page from an LWC with parameters

Tags: lightning-web-components, experience-cloud

I want to navigate a user from lightning experience to experience cloud page. In Lightning Experience, I have created a button on home page and added navigation code. The redirection to experience page works, however I need a way to pass some attributes and intercept them on the LWC added to the experience page. I tried the below approach, but didnt work out. Can someone please suggest if there is any alternative to pass the attributes in this scenario.

Calling LWC:

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';

export default class TabCmp extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement) {
    recordPageUrl;
    connectedCallback() {
        this.communityPage = {
            type: 'standard__webPage',
            attributes: {
                url: 'https://xxxxxxx-dev-ed.my.site.com/xxxx/'
            },
            state: {
                inputParameter : 'Contacts'
            }
        };
        console.log('strigified 1234 ->'+JSON.stringify(this.communityPage));        
        sessionStorage.setItem('pageTransfer', JSON.stringify(this.communityPage.state));
        this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl](this.communityPage)
            .then(url => this.recordPageUrl = url);
    }    
    handleClick(){
        console.log('page url ->'+JSON.stringify(this.communityPage)); //this console display has state value set properly.
        this[NavigationMixin.Navigate](this.communityPage);
    }
}
```

Called LWC added to Experience home page:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';

export default class ServCmp extends LightningElement {
    @api myInput = 'Accounts';
    connectedCallback(){
        var resultMsg = sessionStorage.getItem('pageTransfer');
        console.log('resultMsg->'+resultMsg); //Value comes as null here.
    }
}
```